# "PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist" in django while doing loaddata. database is remote oracle 12c

Tags: python, django, oracle, fixtures, loaddata

while doing loaddata fixture, getting error PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist. Django version is 1.11.12.

> django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-06550: line 10, column 17:
>   PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
>   ORA-06550: line 10, column 9:
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

in python shell, i can create objects but through fixtures, i couldn't. please help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python, but Oracle doesn't lie. If it says that sequence doesn't exist, then

- it really doesn't exist
- it exists, but you reference it in a wrong manner. Non-Oracle people tend to use double quotes while referencing Oracle objects. See the demonstration:

  ```
  SQL> create sequence seq;

  Sequence created.

  SQL> select seq.nextval from dual;

     NEXTVAL
  ----------
           1

  SQL> select "seq".nextval from dual;
  select "seq".nextval from dual
         *
  ERROR at line 1:
  ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
  ```
- it exists, but it is owned by someone else (i.e. not the user you're currently connected to), which means that owner has to `grant select` on it, and you have to reference it using owner name, e.g. `select scott.seq.nextval from dual` (Scott is the owner)

---

Message says that error happened at

> line 10, column 17

so - check that position in code you use and see which option (of the ones I mentioned) helps.